# javascript "translate" these shortcuts

Tags: javascript, shortcut

**EDIT**
Code comes from:
http://jsfiddle.net/sWbfk/

I have this javascript code which I don't understand..

It goes like this:

`return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];`

I tried to 'translate' it in something readable to me but I fail.. Any help is apreciated!

Tried:

```
if ( date1 && ( (date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2) ) ) {
    return "dp-highlight";
} else {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I think the open paren should be before `date1 &&`

Comment: And it returns a two element Array, you are returning a single string.

Comment: Incidentally, `date.getTime() == date1.getTime()` can be `date == date1`.

Comment: @thefourtheye—adding an extra set of parenthesis doesn't make any difference. The expression is essentially `date1 && ( /*other stuff*/ )? trueResult : falseResult;`. Presumably *date1* might be `NaN` or `undefined`, in which case it will skip straight to the false result.

Comment: @RobG As it is, if `date1` is falsy, it will return `""`, but if the open paren is before `date1 &&`, it gives a chance for `date2` validation.

Comment: Yes, but if *date1* is falsey it's likely *NaN*, so the second part shouldn't run either (it includes `date >= date1`). I just took the code at face value. Probably the first test should be `date1 && date2`, then the rest, but only the OP knows. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how it could be rewritten:

```js
return [
    true,
    date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""
];
```

Or even:

```js
var array = [true];

if (date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2))) {
    array.push("dp-highlight");
} else {
    array.push("");
}

return array;
```

Comment: Ahaa.. Thanks a lot sp00m!

Answer (score 1):

It is returning an array of two values

I think you mean something like:

```
if (date1 && (date.getTime() == date1.getTime() || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2))) {
  return [true, "dp-highlight"];
} else {
  return [true, ""];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think code written like this can help to understand what actually is compared.

```
var arr = [true];
var isEqualTime = date.getTime() == date1.getTime();
var x = date2 && date; // if both dates are defined take date
var y = date1 && date; // if both dates are defined take date
var boolValue = isEqualTime || (x >= y <= date2);
var z = date1 && boolValue; // set z true, false or undefined.

if(z){
    arr.push("dp-highlight");
}else{
    arr.push("");
}
```

Hope it helps.